# Why do we get 1 as remainder on the second println?

Tags: java, coding-style, modulus

```
package PracticePackage;

public class whileLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i=1;

        System.out.println("Quotient "+i/2);    
        System.out.println("Remainder "+i%2);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem in a bit more detail? It's not clear what you actually want nor why the code shown doen't satisfy your needs.

Comment: You got 1 because `1 % 2 == 1`.  What did you expect instead?

Comment: I was expecting 0. How does it become 1 ? Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the fomula that Java uses to yield the remainder of its operands:

```
(a/b)*b+(a%b)
```

where `a` is the dividend and `b` is the divisor.

so in your case it's like:

```
int i = 1; 
int b = 2;
int result = (i / b) * b + (i % b);
```

hence the result `1` rather than `0`

Answer (score 0):

because integers are not real numbers so you get 1 as answer and the real part of remainder is ignored since you defined `i` as an integer

Comment: Okay. But remainder is 0 and zero is real. Why is 0 not the output? I am confused. and 0 is an integer too.

Comment: remainder is 1 since 1+(0*2) = 1

Answer (score 0):

> 1/2 = 0.5

you defined `i` as `int`

Integral division in java takes floor of the answer if the answer is a real number so 1/2 becomes 0, making 1%2 equal to 1

I hope that explains.